# How do I know all the ip address used by the ip cameras in the network

Tags: rtsp, ip-camera

There are many ip cameras connected to a network. I have access to the network and also got some of the rtsp IPs. I want to scan the IPs of all the cameras in the network. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [nmap](https://nmap.org/download.html). Then scan for the range of your network like 149.228.115.* y the webcam is in the same segment than yours

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you please explain me?

Comment: IP format is `rtsp://172.17.x.x/stream1`

Comment: Could be enough using range 172.17.*.*